# jQuery/CSS - Change IFRAME Height when click on button inside the iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working on a simple HTML/jQuery script.
Right now when i click on the button which is inside the iframe it is changing the iframe's height that is calling the content with the button.

Take a look at the code:

```
<div id="outerdiv" style="padding:20px;border:2px solid red;">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/iframe.php" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the iframe.php content:

```
 <HTML>
 <head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
 <div style="display:block;height:300px;">
    <h3>The iframe content</h3>  
        <button type="button" id="SuperWebF1">Click me to resize the holding Iframe!</button>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
        $('#inneriframe', window.parent.document).animate({height:'900px'}, 500);

    })
    </script>
```

The problem is coming when i try to add this:

```
<style>
#outerdiv
{
   width:400px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   border:2px solid #fff;
}

#inneriframe
{
   position:absolute;
   width:400px;
   height:700px;
   border:0px;
}
</style>

<div id="outerdiv" style="padding:20px;border:2px solid red;">
    <iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/iframe.php" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
</div>
```

As you can see i've added a `<style>` tag where i added CSS for the elements `outerdiv` and the iframe `inerriframe` and now when i click on the button it's not chaning the iframe's height.

When i remove the `<style>....</style>` tags and all the content inside them the script is starting to work again.

Here is the demo: http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/
This is the working demo when i have not added the `<style></style>` tags.

Can you help me set up the CSS for these elements and make the jQuery script works as well ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The event will not trigger it's function when the document is not fully loaded inside the `iframe` page.

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
    $('#inneriframe', window.parent.document).animate({height:'900px'}, 500);

});
</script>
```

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#SuperWebF1").on('click',function(){
    $('#inneriframe', window.parent.document).animate({height:'900px'}, 500);

});
});
</script>
```

For it to listen to the `click` event when all the `.css`,`.js` and whole documents in the page are completely ready.

I hope this will help?